# how to create WIRED Magazine type of iPad application, ideas needed

Tags: ipad

Can someone please give me an idea of how the WIRED Magazine on iPad works, I want to build a similar application and want to know how I should start this.

Thanks
Saurabh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's built using Adobe InDesign CS5 and Adobe Digital Publishing Solution which should have it's first public release 'late summer'.

The magazine is designed in InDesign as normal and then passed through a the Digital Content Bundler, this creates a .issue file which can then be read by the Digital Content Reader (the actual App).

Comment: ok... means i have to create a Digital Content Reader on iPad .. can you please give some inputs on how should i build this.

Comment: I believe the Adobe Digital Publishing solution would include the content reader. If you don't want to use those tools then you'll need to architect it from scratch and that's beyond the scope of an answer here. I'm sure you'd be able to hire some application architecture expertise to help you with this.